# fine-tune nanoGPT for instructions

Tags: fine-tuning, large-language-models

I've been playing around with nanoGPT, and recently I decided I wanted to fine-tune it using the dolly instruction set. This data set consists of roughly 15k examples and each example has the following features: question-type, context, instruction, and response. For my first go around at fine-tuning nanoGPT, I threw away the question-type feature, and then prefixed the other categories with "CONTEXT: ", "INSTRUCTION: ", "RESPONSE: " respectively, I then proceeded to concatenate them all together, tokenize them, and then train nanoGPT on the resulting text. That worked fine, for the most part, but now I want to train nanoGPT in a slightly different way.

The other way I would like to train nanoGPT is as follows: I again prefix each of the categories, but this time I would like to only concatenate the context and instruction together. The training loop I would like to use is something like this: input the the context and instruction together, let the model generate a response, and then compare that with response in dolly (e.g. take the cross-entropy loss between the generated response and the response from the dataset). The problem with this is that the way nanoGPT works (as far as I can tell), you feed in a block of text (usually 1024 tokens) and the target is that same block of text but shifted by 1, and the loss is computed between the next token and the output. Essentially, the forward call for nanoGPT only gives the probability distribution for the next character given the block. So it would seem that I need to either change the model somehow (which is undesirable), or I need to change the training loop. Now, in nanoGPT, there is a generate method, but it is explicitly decorated with a @torch.no_grad(). I've tried commenting out this decorator, but run into problems when doing so.

So I am at a bit of a loss of what to do from here. If anyone has any suggestions or know of any resources, I'd be very grateful. I am still quite new to this stuff so I am not sure what I am hoping to do is even reasonable.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @CWcx, and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! You may be able to get a faster answer to this question if you clearly specify your question in the title and somewhere in the body, perhaps on its own line. Thanks!